# Outlook Add in pinning does not work in Shared folders Outlook Web - SupportsPinning and SupportsSharedFolders

Tags: reactjs, outlook, outlook-web-addins

We have implemented an Outlook Add in that uses the **SupportsPinning** option from Req Set 1.5 and the **SupportsSharedFolders** option from Req Set 1.8. Both options are working fine in Windows Outlook Native client but malfunction in Outlook.com, outlook.office365.com, OWA (tested in latest Chrome, IE and Edge).

These are the steps and the outcome:

1. Open Shared Inbox in web outlook
2. Select email
3. Open Add-in
4. Pin Add-in
5. Select another email
6. OUTCOME: Add-in window closes, EXPECTED: Add-in window remains open

The other strange thing is that if you then select another message, the add-in remains closed BUT if you select an email that you previously opened the add-in on, in the shared inbox, the add-in reopens.

Does anyone know why this behaviour is occurring? Is there a way around it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also faced the problems too.

Outlook OWA still doesn't fully provide that feature.

You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane)

Docs say that this feature is not supported on outlook.com.

So, we have no choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stefan. I seem to have no problem using this feature at Outlook.com _except_ in the case when it's attempted in shared folders. The inbox seems to allow pinning without trouble. 

In addition to that the document you refered to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane) states the following:
> ...the pinnable task panes feature was introduced in requirement set 1.5, it's currently only > available to Microsoft 365 subscribers using the following...
> *Modern Outlook on the web*. What is *Modern Outlook on the web*

Comment: OWA has several versions. classical outlook.com, and then outlook.live.com beta (This is called modern OWA), and then outlook.com on office 365 subscription. These are different. outlook personal account we're using is not the Modern OWA. Outlook in Office 365 subscription plan is more Modern OWA. (Actually, they have different versions)

Comment: OK, I'm trying to determine that given that my target audience are commonly going to be people with an Office 365 subscription (i.e. a work email address) can they use a web version where the pinnable task pane might work..,.? In addition to this, I have no problem using Pinnable task in the users' inbox on most platforms including outlook.office.com and outlook.office365.com. It is only problem inside of shared folders... Thanks for your assistance on this topic Stefen. For those that are interested I have lodged a ticket with MS [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1433)